# Convert from one date format to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert this date 16:07:19 to format as July 19, 2016 in javascript. Should i implement the complete functionality or do we have any readily available thing to use in javascript to do the same? Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several readily-available things for this. The flavor of the week is MomentJS.

Comment: There's really NOTHING on the internet to answer this already?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nagesh521/g8kmhvnm/

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Than you could do for instance

```
moment('2016-01-01').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```